# ¿Cómo hacer que los botones de selección múltiple respondan al hacer clic?

Tags: css, bootstrap, django

Tengo una selección múltiple y me gustaría poder hacer clic en ella para manejar las respuestas en una página /getmatch. Por el momento no tengo ninguna señal visual de que he seleccionado cosas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ¿cómo hacer que la selección de varios elementos responda?

Aqui esta el codigo de la pagina que da estos botones:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

   <style>
      .elements {
        display: block;
      }
      ul.items {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }
      li.item {
        flex: 1 0 20%;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 2px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
        text-align: center;
      }
      .col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
    </style>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
      <h3><br>Tell me something about you... </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <section class="content-section-a">

    <div class="container">
      <dt>
        <span>Pick the keywords you want to express when wearing perfume</span>
      </dt>

    <form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
      {% for keyword in keywords %}
        <div class="elements">
            <ul class="items ">
               <li class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                 <div class="box">
                 <div data-toogle="buttons" class="col">
                    <span>{{ keyword.title }}</span>
                 </div>
                 </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" >


{% endblock %}
```

Intenté anadir cosas en la balisa

```
button:hover{background-color:orange;}

button:focus{background-color:red;}
```

Pero no modifiqué cualquiera cosa.

## Con CSS

```
<style>
  .elements {
    display: block;
  }
  .items {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item {
    flex: 1 0 20%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
  }
  .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .item:hover { background-color:orange; }

  .item-check {
    display: none;
  }
  .item-name {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
  }
  .item .item-check:checked + .item-name {
    background-color: rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
  }

</style>

...

<form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
  {% for keyword in keywords %}
    <div class="elements">
        <ul class="items col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <li class="item">
            <label>
              <input class="item-check" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value= {{ keyword.title }} />
              <div class="item-name">{{ keyword.title }}</div>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Pero tengo este situacion con la animacion `.item:hover` alrededor del nombre y me gustaría que el botón interior se extendiera hasta este .item:hover :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el elemento con la clase col supongo que son los botones que salen no?. De ser así podrías con JQuery o JavaScript detectar el evento click y asignar un color al elemento que has hecho click.

Comment: Mejor que un color, una clase CSS

Comment: @Sjuan76 mejor mejor.

Comment: @SJuan76 ¡Con mucho gusto! ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la intención es usar solo `CSS`, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

- Por cada `keyword` creamos un `<label>`
- Dentro de cada `<label>` metemos:

  - un `<input type="checkbox">`el cual almacenará el valor del `keyword`
  - un `<div>` en el cual se visualizará el nombre del `keyword`

Cada vez que se haga `click` en el `<label>`, el `<input>` dentro cambiará de seleccionado (`checked`) a no seleccionado (`unchecked`).

Utilizando la pseudo-clase [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) y el selector de [hermano adyacente (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_hermanos_adyacentes) podremos cambiar los estilos del `<div>` cuando el `<input>` este seleccionado.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.elements {
  display: block;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
}
.item-check {
  display: none;
}
.item-name {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}
.item-check:checked + .item-name {
  background-color: rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
}
.item-name:hover,
.item-check:checked + .item-name:hover {
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<form action="/getmatch" method="POST">
  <div class="elements">
    <ul class="items">
      <li class="item">
        <label>
          <input class="item-check" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
          <div class="item-name">Keyword 1</div>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <label>
          <input class="item-check" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
          <div class="item-name">Keyword 2</div>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que busco. Sin embargo tengo problemas con los ul. Voy a puestar mia pregunta al dia

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica el problema con los `li` es porque no has copiado correctamente mi `CSS` ni el `HTML`

Comment: Sí, lo siento... ¿sabes que puedo ponerlos uno al lado del otro mientras no se desborde a la derecha?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica, ¿podrías compartirme un ejemplo de lo que te sucede? No me queda claro cual es el problema, entiendo que puede ser un problema de [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). PD: he actualizado mi respuesta para mejorar el efecto `hover`

Comment: Por seguro, es [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424135/pilar-objetos-como-un-selector-de-elementos-m%c3%baltiples-con-html-y-css) que he tratado de resolver sin éxito durante varios días.

Answer (score 0):

Solución con jQuery:

1. Exporta el cdn de jQuery (o descargalo a tu local): `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. Añade una clase css (o lo haces directamente con jQuery).

```
.botonSeleccionado {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

3. Añade la clase boton(si quieres cambiarla por algo más descriptivo mejor.) al elemento html.

```
<div data-toogle="buttons" class="col boton">
</div>
```

4. Crea un fichero tipo JavaScript ejemplo.js.
   Modificar según tus preferencias.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      ponerColor();
   });
   function ponerColor() {          
      $('.boton').on('click', function() {
         $(this).addClass('botonSeleccionado');
      })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Creo que deberías usar `toggleClass`, de lo contrario no volver a "no seleccionado"